# Yii custom ajax search in gridview with different models

Tags: php, ajax, yii

I want to customise the yii gridview search for my model with some checkboxes above the gridview that don't belong to the model but will affect the search result. It's about a contact search that should be modified by flags user can select. I don't know how I can do ajax requests so that the value of the checkboxes are avaiable in the model search() function.

```
<?php
// print all flags
echo '<table class="flag_table"><tr>';
echo '<tr><th>Flags:</th></tr>';
foreach($flagRows as $key=>$value)
{
    echo '<td>';
    echo CHtml::tag('span', array(), "$value->flag:&nbsp;");
    echo CHtml::checkBox('flagId__'.$value->id, false, array('value'=>"$value->id"));
    echo '</td>';
}
echo '</tr></table>';

$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'contact-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'filter'=>$model,
//'cssFile'=>Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/css/grid_view.css',
'columns'=>array(
    'firm',
    'last_name',
    'forename',
    'street',
    'city',
    'mobile_number',
    'email',
    'search_word',
    array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
    ),
),
)); ?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You say that the checkboxes don't belong to the model but will affect the search result. How exactly do the checkbox values affect the search results then? Are they connected to a relation of the model? It would be helpful if you could show that part of your code because without it my answer will be vague. The basic idea is that you have to send the checkbox values to a controller, have that controller return the new data, then update the grid view.

Comment: @frostyterrier Hey Frosty, I have an additional mysql db where flags are mapped to contact ids. This table should affect my contact ar search if flag checkboxes are selected, I don't know how I can change the data of the CActiveDataProvider that is returned by the search() function 'return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
   'criteria'=>$criteria,
            'pagination'=>array(
                'pageSize'=>25,
            ),
  ));'

Answer (score 1):

I still don't have a complete understanding of the flags but I think I have enough information to give you an example. Here it goes:

In your view, add a form around the checkboxes:

```
echo CHtml::form('','post', array('id' => 'checkbox-form')); 
echo '<table class="flag_table"><tr>';
echo '<tr><th>Flags:</th></tr>';
foreach($flagRows as $key=>$value)
{
    echo '<td>';
    echo CHtml::tag('span', array(), "$value->flag:&nbsp;");
    echo CHtml::checkBox('flagId__'.$value->id, false, array('value'=>"$value->id"));
    echo '</td>';
}
echo '</tr></table>';
echo CHtml::endForm();
```

In your view, add this to your cgridview:

```
'beforeAjaxUpdate' => "function(id, options){
    options['data'] = getContactGridData(id);
}",
```

In your view, add this javascript below:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('updateGrid', "

function getContactGridData(id)
{
   var inputSelector = '#'+id+' .filters input, '+'#'+id+' .filters select';
   var origData = $.param($(inputSelector));
   return $('#checkbox-form').serialize() + '&' + origData;
}

$(function(){

    $('#checkbox-form').change(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            type: 'get',
            success: function(data) {
               var id = 'emoticon-grid'; 
               $.fn.yiiGridView.update(id, {data: getContactGridData(id)});
            }
        }); 
        return false;
    });
});

", CClientScript::POS_END);
```

*Credit to [this thread](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/14242-modifying-cgridviews-default-filtersearch-behaviour/) for helping me with the above.

Then in your existing controller method - the one used to fill the gridview - you need to check to see if any of the flag values have been set, and adjust the $model->search criteria accordingly.

I don't have enough information to know exactly how the $model->search criteria needs to be adjusted but you will need to use the format below. The format below is just a random example, not directly related to your code.

```
$model = new ModelName('search');
$model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values

if(isset($_GET['cat_id'])){
    $model->getDbCriteria()->mergeWith(array(
        'condition' => 'cat_id = :cat_id',
        'params' => array(':cat_id' => 1),
     ));
 }

 $this->render('index',array(
     'model'=>$model,
 ));
```

You should check out the [CDbCriteria page](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria) because it explains mergeWith and there are also other methods like addInCondition() and addCondition() which you can use to modify the search criteria.

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: the ajax update didn't work out for me but I got a working solution with renderPartial where I render the grid each time new a user search input has been done and the dataProvider has been updated

Comment: Great, that works too. That's actually how I do it in one of my personal projects, but this seemed like the more "Yii" way to do it.